# Scooby Dum LEGO character?

Tags: minifigures

I like playing with LEGO sets a lot. I especially like the Scooby Doo sets.  I'm wondering if LEGO has ever made a Scooby Dum character? Scooby Dum is Scooby Doo's cousin.

Comment: VTC This is not an official Lego site. We are fans of Lego, but do not have access to the information you are looking for.

Comment: @Gliderman even though we as a site are not affiliated with Lego, that does not prevent us from answering the question with what has or has not already been released by Lego. I am going to go with unlikely, as there is no listing under the [Lego website](http://www.lego.com/en-us/scoobydoo/characters). Also, isn't the character spelled Scooby "Dum" as opposed to "Dumb"?

Comment: @user2813274 Oh wow, just reread question. I had seen it was addressed as if we were Lego, and assumed it was something we couldn't answer. Sorry about that!

Answer (score 1):

One can never be certain about *everything* Lego has ever produced, but If you search on [Brickset](http://brickset.com/sets/theme-Scooby-Doo) or [Bricklink](http://www.bricklink.com/v2/search.page?q=scooby) for the word "scooby" you don't, at this time, find anything except Scooby-Doo.